# Is Goldblatt's talk about Waley available on-line?

Tags: translation

Is there any on-line source for Howard Goldblatt's article "Why I hate Arthur Waley."?  It is in *Translation Quarterly* (1999) No. 13 & 14,  pp.33 -- 48.

I have even found pictures of Goldblatt on the stage where he delivered the talk, in Hong Kong. But so far I find no written copy (or video) on-line, even through my university library.  I will say I hope he is being ironic about "hating" Waley.  But however that may be, I would like to know what he says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Baidu Wenku](https://wenku.baidu.com/view/f22696fcf705cc17552709ff.html) has a copy.

It's free it doesn't require any points or coins or whatever their currency is. Just click 下载文档.

---

[Google Books](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=BaRlSVEwhjkC&pg=PA351&lpg=PA351&dq=%22I%20began%20my%20study%20of%20Chinese%20the%20year%22&source=bl&ots=ngXc-J6RMJ&sig=ACfU3U1aw_Ht5ftMRvJel2Dx4G1tIUnaQw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjL5My7go3vAhWeSEEAHc31CX0Q6AEwAHoECAMQAw#v=onepage&q=%22I%20began%20my%20study%20of%20Chinese%20the%20year%22&f=false) also seems to have a scanned copy here from the book *China and Her Biographical Dimensions*. Although, it appears that some pages may be missing?

---

Here's the individual images extracted from the PDF

> [image]
> [image]
> [image]
> [image]
> [image]
> [image]
> [image]
> [image]

Comment: Terrific.  Even with two pages missing, the Google books conveys a great deal of what Goldblatt says.  But when I click on Baidu Wenku it tells me I should have the Baidu app.  I might go ahead an install it.  Do you see a way to download without installing it? Instead of downloading a new app, now that I have seen the bulk of the essay, I might just have my library get the book so I can use it at leisure to get quotes and citations.

Comment: @ColinMcLarty I'm not sure. I'm logged into Baidu on my browser and it downloads immediately on PC. I've added the individual images from the PDF into my answer but I can also upload the PDF somewhere for you if you'd like.

Comment: @ColinMcLarty This is the link: https://we.tl/t-lqkOfVXPqD. You should have also received an email as well.

Comment: @ Mou某  Got it!  Thanks.